# Is the truncated exponential series for matrices injective?

Tags: matrices

If $k$ is a field of characteristic $p$, we can define a map $\exp:\mathfrak{gl}_n(k)\to GL_n(k)$ by:

$$\exp(A)=\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}\frac{A^i}{i!}$$

In the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/398006/truncated-exponential-map-from-mathfrakgl-n-to-gl-n), we see that if $A^p=B^p=0$, and if $\exp(A)=\exp(B)$, then $A=B$.  So if $p>n$, $\exp$ is injective when restricted to nilpotents.  I'd like to know whether or not $\exp$ is injective on all of $\mathfrak{gl}_n(k)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if there is any nice characterisation of injectiveness, but the truncated matrix exponential is not injective in all cases. Let $p=3>n=2$ and $A=\pmatrix{1&\ast\\ 0&0}$. Then $A^m=A$ for every $m\ge1$ and
$$\exp(A) = I + A + \frac12 A^2 = I + A + 2A = I = \exp(0).$$